# ModSecurity not blocking attacks

Tags: apache, mod-security

I am using ModSecurity 2.7 on a Centos machine. I just gave `yum install mod_security`, set `SecRuleEngine On` and restarted httpd. Even if ModSecurity is working (looking at ModSecurity and httpd error logs) it does not block any attack (a tried a xss and a path traversal). Any help?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give us much information. What does your config  look like? Which ruleset do you use? What kind of attack did you try? What did the logfile say?

Just a guess: Are you using the OWASP Core Ruleset? Do you need to link the rules you want to use to the activated_rules folder?

Best,
Ronald

Comment: Thank you Ronald. Actually I misconfigured my httpd.conf not including the OWASP rules as you said. If others struggle in this issue I suggest the following tutorial (apart from the installation paragraph which can be done simply using yum).
http://chandank.com/webservers/apache/apache-web-server-hardening-security?start=5

Thanks again for your time